# Bluetooth BLE device not getting Bonded after pairing process

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth

I am working on BLE and the requirement is as below :

There is a list of devices loaded from my local database.

On Tap of a particular device or row, I have to check that the device is bonded or not and If is it bonded I have to navigate to the particular screen. If not bonded then the pairing dialog is opening successfully and I can also enter the password for pairing that BLE device.

But the issue is after entering the correct password to Pair I can not get the BONDED state of BLE device in my broadcast receiver as below :

(note : We know that If BLE is not bonded and we try to connect than the pairing dialog will open automatically.)

Please check below code :

```
 private fun initializeBluetoothBroadcastReceiver() {
    bluetoothBroadCastReceiver= object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            Log.e("%%%%% ", "%%%%% inside onreceive")
            val action = intent.action
            if (action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED) {
                Log.e("%%%%% ", "%%%%% inside ACTION_STATE_CHANGED")
                if (bleManager.bluetoothGatt?.device?.bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    Log.e("%%%%% ", "%%%%% inside BOND_BONDED")
                    if (isBleDeviceConnected) {
                        Log.e("%%%%% ", "%%%%% inside isBleDeviceConnected")
                        bleManager.bluetoothGattCallback?.writeTime()
                        loadBatteryStatusFragement(false)
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.e("%%%%% ", "%%%%% inside not BOND_BONDED")
                }
            }else{
                Log.e("%%%%% ", "%%%%% inside ACTION_STATE_CHANGED ELSE")
            }
        }
    }
    val filter1 = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
    filter1.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)
    registerReceiver(bluetoothBroadCastReceiver, filter1)
}
```

So, If the BLE device is not paired, If I am trying then -- > Pairing popup is opening and after successful password entered, I am getting below log :

```
%%%%%: %%%%% inside onreceive
%%%%%: %%%%% inside ACTION_STATE_CHANGED ELSE
```

and not getting **inside BOND_BONDED**

What might be the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the FLAG used.

Instead of using this flag : `ACTION_STATE_CHANGED`

```
if (action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED) {
```

We have to use this flag : `ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED`

```
if (action == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED) {
```

Resolved code is as below :

```
private fun initializeBluetoothBroadcastReceiver() {
    bluetoothBroadCastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val action = intent.action
            if (action == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED) {
                if (bleManager.bluetoothGatt?.device?.bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    if(isBleDeviceConnected)
                    {
                        performNecessaryAction()
                    }else{
                        showConnectionFailedDialog()
                    }

                } else if (bleManager.bluetoothGatt?.device?.bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                    try {
                        isBleDeviceConnected = false
                        DialogUtils.showPairingFailedDialog(
                            this@HomeActivity,
                            objLanguageJson?.error_message?.err_battery_pairing_failed
                        )
                        performNecessaryAction()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                } else if (bleManager.bluetoothGatt?.device?.bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    Log.e("%%%%% ", "%%%%% bonding none")
                }
            } else if (action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED) {
                val state =
                    intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR)
                Log.e("%%%%% ", "%%%%% state name >>> " + state)
                when (state) {
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF -> {
                        Log.e("%%%%% ", "%%%%% bluetooth turns off ")
                        val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter =
                            BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
                        val isEnabled: Boolean = bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled
                        if (!isEnabled) {
                            bluetoothAdapter.enable()
                        }
                        if (isBleDeviceConnected) {
                            isBleDeviceConnected = false
                           
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF -> {

                    }
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON -> {
                    }
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON -> {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
    registerReceiver(bluetoothBroadCastReceiver, filter)
}
```